Issue with Github compare after a revert
This is  the layout of my Git projects.
Master < Dev < Dev2
I have been working on changes on Dev2 for months, and recently moved them up to Dev to get ready for deployment.  In the mean time a priority change came in which needs to go to production BEFORE my changes.  Therfore I had to revert 3 pull requests to remove my code changes from Dev.
After the priority code goes to prod I want to re-add my code back to Dev, however when I do a compare now between
Dev <-- Dev 2 , none of the code changes I reverted are showing up.
If i do the compare the other way Dev2 <-- Dev, they are all showing , but the wrong way (ie: if i merged this, it would delete all my recent changes off Dev2 to have it back in sync with Dev)
My question is how can I make my reverted changes show up again when I do a comparison between the 2 branches? I will need to merge these changes back in next week and for now I am not sure how I can do it if they are not showing on the pull request.
